# What's this material of my deck?

Tags: deck, materials

I always thought my deck is wood, but my neighbor came and said it's not. Now I'm in doubt. Anyone can identify the material and how to maintain it? Do I need to use sealer on it? Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do not know the material, but think it is some kind of moulded plastic/composite material.  It should be maintenance free.

Answer (score 6):

The material looks to be TREX. It is widely available from a number of sources.

Here is the [Care and Cleaning Guide](https://images.trex.com/is/content/trexcompany/trex-decking-care-and-cleaning-010820pdfpdf#_ga=2.5337971.1139984313.1710001968-511624694.1710001968&_gac=1.119035003.1710001968.Cj0KCQiArrCvBhCNARIsAOkAGcVyKQhUJQmIMry61kwohQBZhRiGfpDfCE_AZnJDgTwaZOMOpjLGfCwaAqPgEALw_wcB)

In the event the product is not Trex, the care and cleaning for most all composite decking is the same.